# saving toggle button state in listview using sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I have a toggle button in the listview. I use sharedpreferenece to store its state.
I succeeded in storing the state but i dont know how to retrieve it. Have seen many examples but my structure is bit different so confused how to retrieve the stored state. Please provide me some clue.

Main.java

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

```
ListView lv;
List<ResolveInfo> list;
List<Drawable> icons;
PackageManager pm;
ArrayAdapter ar;
//boolean on;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //apps=new ArrayList<String>();
    //result=new ArrayList<String>();
    //timer=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    //iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    int size=mApps.size();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Number of apps :" +Integer.toString(size),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Collections.sort(mApps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
    ar=new ArrayAdapter(this,mApps);
    setListAdapter(ar);
 }
```

ArrayAdapter.java

public class ArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, List<ResolveInfo> mApps) 
{
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mApps = mApps;
    this.context=context;
    apps=new ArrayList<String>();
    timer=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    //loadSavedState(context);

}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHendler hendler;
     //LoadPreferences();
    /*SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("", MODE_PRIVATE);
    b1.setChecked()*/


    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent, false);
        hendler = new ViewHendler();
        hendler.textLable = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        hendler.iconImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        hendler.checked=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        convertView.setTag(hendler);
        //sp=context.getSharedPreferences(FILE, 0);
        //b1.setChecked(sp.getBoolean(,))
    } 
    else 
    {
       hendler = (ViewHendler) convertView.getTag();
    }


    ResolveInfo info = this.mApps.get(position);
    hendler.iconImage.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));
    hendler.textLable.setText(info.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()));

    final ToggleButton b1=(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    hendler.checked.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
    b1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(b1.isChecked())
            {
            View v = (View) buttonView.getParent();
            final ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

            app = tv.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(context, app, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);dialog.setTitle("Select type");
            im1=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Option1 pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    final TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(context); timePicker.setIs24HourView(true); timePicker.setCurrentHour(00); timePicker.setCurrentMinute(00);

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Set Limit")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    timePicker.requestFocus();
                                    items=items+1; 
                                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
                                    hr=timePicker.getCurrentHour(); min=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                                    int t1=hr*3600; int t2=min*60; time=t1+t2;

                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Limit  "+hr + " hour "+ min+" min ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); cmin = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                    apps.add(app);   Log.e("app",app);
                                    timer.add(time); Log.e("time",Integer.toString(time));


                                    sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                                    Editor editor=sp.edit();
                                    editor.putBoolean("", b1.isChecked());
                                    editor.commit();
                                    start();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {b1.setChecked(false);}
                             })
                            .setView(timePicker).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });
            dialog.show();
            }//ischecked()

            else
            {
                sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                Editor editor=sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("", b1.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    }); 

    return convertView;

}

 public void start()
{
              Intent i=new Intent(context,MonitorService.class);
              i.putStringArrayListExtra("apps", apps);
              i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("timer", timer);
              i.putExtra("items", items);
              i.putExtra("day",cmin);
              context.startService(i);
}

public void start1()
{
              Intent i=new Intent(context,MonitorService1.class);
              i.putStringArrayListExtra("apps", apps);
              i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("timer", timer); 
              i.putExtra("items", items);
              context.startService(i);
}
class ViewHendler{
    public ToggleButton checked;
    TextView textLable;
    ImageView iconImage;
}


public final int getCount() {
    return mApps.size();
}

public final Object getItem(int position) {
    return mApps.get(position);
}

public final long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: You're using different **keys** for storing and retrieving values. And something for later. Use `isChecked` boolean value instead of `b1.isChecked()` method and get the reference of the `ToggleButton` (b1) by the handler not `findViewById(..) otherwise the meaning of the handler for toggle button is lost.

Comment: hey i did that..but it doesnt work..Storing the state is proper but then how to retrieve the state in my code?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend that you consider using a database for this, or that you grab all of the saved values ahead of time so that you're not querying SharedPreferences during getView() in your adapter. With the way you've designed the adapter currently, you're going to be pulling data out of SharedPreferences every time the user scrolls the ListView, which is bad practice and will make for janky scrolling.

But, to address your problem, it looks like your *value storage* and *value retrieval* are not using the same keys. When you look for the value, you're using this:

```
hendler.checked.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false));
```

But when you set the value, you're using this:

```
editor.putBoolean("", b1.isChecked());
```

The code to store the value needs to use the same key (`"CheckValue"+position`) as the code that retrieves the value. So, your storage code should look like this:

```
sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor=sp.edit();
editor.putBoolean("CheckValue"+position, b1.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

Comment: thank you..i did that correction now i see that state is stored properly with row id.

Comment: But how to retrieve the saved state? Any clue please

Comment: if i use this stmt - >hendler.checked.setChecked(sp.getBoolean("CheckValue"+position, false)); it gives me null pointer exception

Comment: If you're getting an NPE, then one of the following are null: hendler,  hendler.checked, or sp. Make sure that you're initializing all of those before you get to that line of code.

Comment: Put this at the top of your getView() method: final SharedPreferences sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);